# how to redirect traffic to different websites by numbers of click?

Tags: javascript, traffic, tracker

for example I have 100 000 visitors 
how can
I redirect traffic like that :

20k visitors to website A 
And 50k visitors to website B 
And 30k    visitors to website C

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to find out what kind of questions Stack Overflow [is](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [isn't](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) intended for. This question is [asking for a solution without attempting to show any work](https://can-i-haz.codes/). Please provide some code to help us work with you to find a solution.

Comment: Are you talking about dynamically changing a hyperlink with JavaScript? What is your specific programming problem?

Comment: yes I want dynamic redirect

Answer (score 0):

Either you keep count of how many people you redirected and change the link's target accordingly, or you can use the power of statistics and generate a random number between 0 and 1 - then redirect the user to A if it's less than 0.2, to B if it's between 0.2 and 0.7 and otherwise to C.
That way, it also doesn't matter if you have 200k visitors or only 100 - statistically, 20% will go to A, 50% to B and 30% to C.